# node-config Config is `undefined` in typescript jest context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a typescript module that works in dev and production. it uses https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config I am trying to import it into jest to write tests against and it throws an error that indicates the config object is undefined

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (src/email/email.service.ts:1877:43)
```

from

```
import config from 'config'
console.log('**********CONFIG GET*********', config); // undefined
const sendgridToken: string = config.get('socialApi.value') // throws error
```

I'd expect config to be defined its the default export of the config module

environment:

```
node-config version: config@3.2.4
node-version: 12.13.1
tsc -v
Version 3.7.4
ts-jest@24.3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
import config from 'config'
```

write this

```
import * as config from 'config'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable [esModuleInterop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) in your tsconfig

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
   }
```

By default, `import config from "config"` acts the same as `const config = require("config").default`, and `config` has `module.exports = ...` (ie has no default export).

`esModuleInterop` wraps module.exports with default.

```
module.exports = ...
module.exports = { default: module.exports }
// it is pseudo-code
```

See more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).